# Why should I find EditText in the onclick method

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am a newbie to programming. Lately I am trying to study android & java on my own so I have very basic doubts please help me to clear them.

I want  to display the text typed in EditText after clicking the button(using onClick attribute in XML file). My program works only if I find the EditText inside "Press" Method
but not if find the text field globally. Can anyone explain it

Here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {    
        String text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void Press  (View view) {

         EditText input =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_input);
        text= input.getText().toString();

          Toast.makeText(this, text,

          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } 
    }
```

XML file

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/main_input"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/start"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="86dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/maiinput"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="178dp"
        android:onClick="Press"
        android:text="Start" />
```

Comment: Where did you put `input =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_input);` first? And where did you declare `EditText input` ?

Comment: below mainactivity itself.i am very new to programming so plz forgive me 4 the mistakes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {    
String text;
EditText input;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
input =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_input);
}

public void clickme(View view) {
  text= input.getText().toString();
  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, text,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 } 
}
```

and change your `onClick="clickme"` to your `Button` in your `activity_main.xml`

Comment: ur code works fine...

i tried  to find the edittext below mainactivity itself like this

public class MainActivity extends Activity {    
      
EditText input  =   (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_input);                                                        

but it didn't show any errors then but only after running it showed the error.can u explain y that happened

Answer (score 1):

```
private EditText text;
private Button ok;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    ok=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, text.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}
```

You have to write in this way hope this works for you

Answer (score 1):

From comments:

> i tried to find the edittext below mainactivity itself like this public class MainActivity extends Activity { EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_input); but it didn't show any errors then but only after running it showed the error.can u explain y that happened

You're calling `findViewById()` too early when class member variables are initialized. At that point the activity does not have a `Window` yet and it will NPE.

You should call `findViewById()`:

- in `onCreate()` or later when there's the `Window` and no NPE occurs, and
- after `setContentView()` when there's a view hierarchy to actually find something and non-null can be returned.

Comment: thks man everybody put the code but nobody explained it.now i understand y i made the mistake.wish i  had someone like u to guide me through.

Comment: so only after i put the setcontentview method i have a window right.

Comment: in `onCreate` there's the window and no NPE; after `setContentView()` `findViewById()` can actually find something

Comment: Ok thanks your help is much appreciated.can u tell me where u  have learned this concepts.can u provide  any sites,books,forums where i can learn more efficiently. i cannot find these kind of information from net.

Comment: I've learned it by reading and writing code, especially reading the platform source code, with focus given by some problem at hand such as a bug in a project I'm working on or a SO question.